# Why calculations with variables give a different result than calculations with cell references?

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to get some calculations and I was wondering why my macro was giving a different result than the one I was getting when using it on my worksheet so I've tested this:

[image]

The code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Programaciones")
        Dim Efectivos As Single: Efectivos = .Cells(62, 21) '4.65000009536743
        Dim Llamadas As Single: Llamadas = .Cells(65, 21) '12
        Dim TMO As Long: TMO = .Cells(66, 21) '398.108567311734
        Debug.Print Utilisation(Efectivos, Llamadas, TMO) * Efectivos * 1800 / TMO / Llamadas
        Debug.Print Utilisation(.Cells(62, 21), .Cells(65, 21), .Cells(66, 21)) * .Cells(62, 21) * 1800 / .Cells(66, 21) / .Cells(65, 21)
    End With

End Sub
```

Why does this happen? I've tried changing `Single` to `Double` variable type and got the same result. I know about the floating numbers in vba, but this is more of a question when they are stored in a variable or not.

Edit: Utilisation is a function from Erlang library which has this code

```
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function Utilisation(Agents As Single, CallsPerHalfAnHour As Single, AHT As Long) As Single
'Copyright © T&C Limited 1996, 1999
'Calculate the utilisation percentage for the given number of agents
' Agents is the number of agents available
' CallsPerHalfAnHour is the number of calls received in one hour period
' AHT (Average handle time) is the call duration including after call work in seconds  e.g 180
Dim BirthRate As Single, DeathRate As Single, TrafficRate As Single
Dim Util As Single

On Error GoTo UtilError

     BirthRate = CallsPerHalfAnHour
     DeathRate = 1800 / AHT
'calculate the traffic intensity
     TrafficRate = BirthRate / DeathRate
     Util = TrafficRate / Agents

UtilExit:
     Utilisation = MinMax(Util, 0, 1)
     Exit Function

UtilError:
    Util = 0
    Resume UtilExit

End Function
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Function MinMax(val As Single, Min As Single, Max As Single) As Single
'Apply minimum and maximum bounds to a value
    MinMax = val
    If val < Min Then MinMax = Min
    If val > Max Then MinMax = Max
End Function
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: There will be a conversion from `Double` to `Single` which will alter precision, but we'd need to see the `Utilisation` code.

Comment: @Rory what do you mean with the conversion from `Double` to `Single`? All my variables are `Single`. Also, added the code you asked for.

Comment: Cell values are stored as doubles. What are the actual values in the relevant cells?

Comment: @Rory edited the initial code with the values beside the variable declarations.

Comment: Those don't look correct, since you have decimals in a `Long`. How are you determining those values, and are the cells literal values, or the results of formulas?

Comment: @Rory `Utilisation` function from the worksheet takes decimals for the third argument(you can try) and all my cells have plain values, no formulas anywhere.

Comment: `TMO` equals 380 so `/ .Cells(66, 21)` is not the same as `/TMO`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `Dim TMO As Long` and read the value `TMO = .Cells(66, 21)` which you say is  `398.108567311734` in the cell. Since `Long` can only hold integer numbers (no decimals) the value in `TMO` will be `398` which is not `398.108567311734`.

Therefore you get different results when you calculate with …

- `TMO` which is `398`
- `.Cells(66, 21)` which is `398.108567311734`

Either declare it as `Dim TMO As Double` so the variable can take a decimal value, or make sure when using `.Cells(66, 21)` you convert it into long before `cLng(.Cells(66, 21))` to cut off the decimals.

---

This should give the same result as the variables:

```
Utilisation(.Cells(62, 21), .Cells(65, 21), .Cells(66, 21)) * cSng(.Cells(62, 21)) * 1800 / cLng(.Cells(66, 21)) / cSng(.Cells(65, 21))
```

Note that this line

```
Dim Efectivos As Single: Efectivos = .Cells(62, 21) '4.65000009536743
```

will actually turn the double precision `4.65000009536743` into a single precision. So the value that is in the variable `Efectivos` is `4.65` because it is declared as `Single` and therefore cannot contain a such precise number as `4.65000009536743`.

The following table shows how your values change with the type of variable you use:

[image]

---

Another example:

- Real Life: `10/3 = 3,33333333333333…` 'endlesse amounts of 3
- Single: `cSng(10/3) = 3,333333` '7 digits of accuracy
- Double:`cDbl(10/3) = 3,33333333333333` '15 digits of accuracy

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't know why I was thinking that a `Single` could handle way more decimals than it actually can.

Comment: @Damian if you want to take a deep dive into the [Single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). Single is limited to 7 digits of accuracy. Check my edit.